# Rem Resizing Not Working in Safari

Tags: css, mobile, sass, responsive-design, responsive

We are building a responsive website based on Rem values. The site works fantastic in Chrome and scales perfectly as expected but when tested on Safari the scaling does not occur. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luskin/pcwudrmc/43824/) that replicates the problem. If you resize the width of the browser in chrome the text will resize with it, however on Safari the `font-size` remains the same.

It would seem crazy if Safari did not have this functionality. Does anybody have any experience with this and how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Safari & iOS Safari (both 6 and 7) does not support viewport units (`vw`, `vh`, etc) in `calc()`.
>   https://caniuse.com/#search=calc -> check under **known issues**